# Why run cancelFunc() at the end of the function

Tags: go, go-context, go-gin

when I create a context WithCancel function by golang，why suggest to run the cancelFunc at the end of the function。
I think，assume I use gin framework, After current function run finished，the context of gin will destory。So is it necessary to run the cancelFunc after
define `context.WithCancel(ctx)` , `defer cancelFunc()`

```
func myFunction(ctx *context.Context) error {
    cancelCtx, cancelFunc := context2.WithCancel(ctx)
    defer cancelFunc()

    var (
        successTask = int32(0)
        failTask    = int32(0)
        wg          = &sync.WaitGroup{}
    )

    select {
    case <-cancelCtx.Done():
        break
    default:
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++{
            wg.add(1)

            go func(){
                defer wg.Done()

                err := myLogic()
                if err != nil {
                    atomic.AddInt32(&failTask, 1)
                    cancelFunc()
                    return
                }
                atomic.AddInt32(&successTask, 1)
            }
        }
        
        
    }

    wg.Wait()
    return nil
}
```

the code `defer cancelFunc()`,can i remove this line?

Comment: ["Canceling this context releases resources associated with it, so code should call cancel as soon as the operations running in this Context complete."](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithCancel)

Comment: Also [Canceling in-progress operations](https://go.dev/doc/database/cancel-operations)

Comment: Well, ultimatively because the documentation says so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documentation of [`context.WithCancel()`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithCancel) states you should call `cancel()`, so you should, end of discussion:

> Canceling this context releases resources associated with it, so code should call cancel as soon as the operations running in this Context complete.

The implementation of `context.WithCancel()` may allocate resources or launch goroutines to propagate cancellation, so since the implementation is not in your hands, you *should* call `cancel()`.

Even if in the current version (with current implementation) wouldn't make a difference, you have no guarantee that with a future (or older) version it would still work as intended (e.g. not leaking resources) without calling `cancel()`.